# How to fix Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not execute native bulk manipulation query?

Tags: java, sql, hibernate

I am getting that error and I've tried to fix it, but nothing.

```
int nr = nrfromPar; //13
int nrdays = nrfromPar;//1
Date data = datafromPar; //Thu May 11 23:11:09 EEST 2017

String statusRequest = "UPDATE home "
         + "SET date_ma = :data, nr_days_ma = :nrdays "
         + "WHERE nr_req = :nr";

SQLQuery simpleSQL = session.createSQLQuery(statusRequest );
    simpleSQL.setParameter("data", data);
    simpleSQL.setParameter("nrdays", nrdays);
    simpleSQL.setParameter("nr", nr);
 int a =simpleSQL.executeUpdate();
 System.out.println(a);
```

The result is:

```
Hibernate: 
    UPDATE
        home
    SET
        date_ma = ?,
        nr_days_ma = ? 
    WHERE
        nr_req= ?
1
```

What does this error means: ***"Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: No value specified for parameter 1"*** ?

I want to use nativ sql query, although I use hibernate annotations.

Comment: You have to set the parameters with the values you have.

Comment: And , is your table name `home ac`?

Comment: the table name is home, but I've used alias. Even if I do not use alias, it still does not insert.

Comment: @Alex it is not an insert your query is an update

Comment: Over my life I don't see an `update` with alias

Comment: Is the same result...it still does not insert anything.

Comment: @Alex `1` mean that one row is update it so check your row and you will see that the information are changed, just in case you already enter the same information like before, so if you row contain `sql` and you update it with `sql` of course you will not see that deffirence, so make sure that you enter different values and check if your row is updated or not

Comment: Yes...I'm sorry it took so long. Thank you. It's working.

Comment: you are welcome

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**No value specified for parameter 1**

You get this error, because you don't specify values to `:data, :nrdays, :nr`, it should be something like this :

```
SQLQuery simpleSQL = session.createSQLQuery(statusRequest );
simpleSQL.setParameter("data", some_value);
simpleSQL.setParameter("nrdays", some_value);
simpleSQL.setParameter("nr", some_value);
```

---

Like you can use `?` like this :

```
String statusRequest = "UPDATE home "
         + "SET date_ma = ?, nr_days_ma = ? "
         + "WHERE nr_req = ?";
SQLQuery simpleSQL = session.createSQLQuery(statusRequest );
simpleSQL.setParameter(1, some_value);
simpleSQL.setParameter(2, some_value);
simpleSQL.setParameter(3, some_value);
```

Comment: Yes , think is wrong , mybe `home_ac` or `[home ac]`

Comment: I've done the changes, I got rid of the error...but it does not insert anything...the values are correct, but somehow, something is wrong

Comment: @Alex `...but it does not insert anything` your query is update and not an insert?

Comment: oops @Sami sorry but it was not the name `home ac` it is an alias you makes me make another mistake i believes :D don't worry it happen to best of us